# How to use HTML pages in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I want to use HTML pages in a Windows application using C#.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

Look into the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: in this answer, you have a hyperlink pointing on a code sample from microsoft msdn. Is that not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the `WebBrowser` control?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-the-web-browser-control

This basically puts a browser inside of your app, which is useful.

Maybe you only want the content of the html from a page. That would be [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Drag a WebBrowser control onto your form. Then you can set the HTML like this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>";
```